# Calculating the homotopy class of a smooth map between manifolds

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds

For instance, it is a known result that:

$$\pi_3(SU(N))\simeq \mathbb{Z}, N\ge2 $$

How do i calculate the element of $\mathbb{Z}$ associated to, say, a smooth map
$f:S³\rightarrow SU(N)?$ What are some general results or references on such formulas?

Comment: I think $\frac{1}{24\pi^2}\int\mathrm{tr}\,(f^{-1}\mathrm{d} f)^3$ gives you this by Hurewicz and Chern–Weil, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: You can look at what it does in (co)homology, using the fact that the Hurewicz map in degree $3$ is an isomorphism for each of the spaces.